# SQL query return data after a date. Date set as varcher

Tags: mysql

Trying to run a query that will return all data after a certain date. Date is set as varchar and not as date.

I have:

```
SELECT employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname, custom79 AS  'First Pay Date', custom6 AS  'Agency', custom56 AS  'Country of Homebase'
FROM  `hs_hr_employee` 
WHERE custom6 LIKE  'Brookfield'
AND custom61 LIKE  'active-oam'
AND custom79 >  '13-07-2012'
```

Help would be great as I'm not sure how to convert to date for the query

Using UNIX, phpmyadmin, sql

Comment: `AND STR_TO_DATE(custom79, '%d-%m-%Y') > '2012-07-13'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
SELECT employee_id, emp_firstname, emp_lastname, custom79 AS  'First Pay Date', custom6 AS  'Agency', custom56 AS  'Country of Homebase'
FROM  `hs_hr_employee` 
WHERE custom6 LIKE  'Brookfield'
AND custom61 LIKE  'active-oam'
AND STR_TO_DATE(custom79, '%d-%m-%Y') > '2012-07-13'
```